# Sort a nested Association by another Association

Tags: dataset, associations, map, sorting

I have a nested association of numerous pixel values sorted by sample date (e.g. 20190422C) and futher by a strain percentage (e.g. 0, 30, 50).
[image]

I want to sort it even further using and Association of Rules assigning each sample date to a planar thickness.
[image]

I tried to AssociationThread and AssociationMap the two Associations together but to no avail.  Help?

Comment: Please, consider others that might come to this question & self-answer you have provided. It is much better & helpful to include some actual typed out code & a small sample dataset to work with, rather than a few pictures. As it stands, neither this nor your self-answer are appropriate for this site. If you can do this, I think you should find some upvotes & more importantly, other answers with different methods for your question!

Answer (score 0):

I fixed with a workaround by splitting it up[image]